# Did I set up my book series titles and ISBNs wrong?

Tags: self-publishing, series, isbn

I currently have 4 books all under one series that are self published. The way I have been setting up the titles through Ingramspark and under my ISBNs has been:

> Title: Name of the Book Series
>
> Subtitle: Name of individual book.

I'm wondering if that is correct at all and can't seem to find any information regarding it. Take the *Twilight* series for example, it tells you it's a series in the actual book title. However a book series like "Left Behind" does not have the series name in the title at all, it is only in the first book, yet we know that each book is a part of that series. I'm going to use *Twilight* as my example because they are the closest to how I've been titling the books in my series: If I were to assign a book series like *Twilight* with the individual ISBNs and upload the book to Ingramspark and KDP Amazon, would it be:

> Title: The Twilight Saga:
>
> Subtitle: Eclipse

or

> Title: "Eclipse"
>
> Subtitle: (left blank)

Is there a way to assign individual ISBNs to a specific book series so that a reader who comes across your book, or say a library carrying your books, will know it is a series? I have recently come across information regarding ISSN numbers, but from what I gather, this is not for a book series, but for magazines and other recurring publications. How do you tie together all of your books so that they are recognized globally as a series? KDP Amazon has a box with the option to add your books to a series, but I've seen other self-publishing websites that do not. I have also not seen this option when assigning my ISBN numbers.

**So my question is, how do you title books in a series correctly using the "Title/Subtitle", and how do you tie all of your books together through ISBNs?**

I setup my ISBN numbers through Bowker if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in my last book was this (this is an example, I didn't write this book):

Title: Name of the actual book e.g. The Chamber of Secrets
Subtitle: The series, e.g. The Harry Potter Series

I really hope this helped you. I had this exact same question, when I published my first book.

Comment: I am sorry, my punctuation in my answer was really bad. I forgot you can't leave a line. Sorry!

Comment: If you sign up for a full account, you'll be able to edit your posts to fix mistakes like that. I've taken the liberty of doing it for you this time.

Answer (score -1):

You first would want to name the series (example below), then following along that as a base line make the tiles of the book relate to the series' name.

Series name:  Tales of the Twisted
Book names: Valley of balloons, The Darkest Corner, and The Wandering

(These titles are all copyrighted)